# Converting private class from Kotlin to Java via bytecode

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When the Kotlin code is compiled into Java byte code what happens with private class. I ask it, because private classes are absent in Java.

Comment: @Md.Asaduzzaman I'm not sure that's relevant here.

Comment: @Roland 
private classes are absent in java, John Anders is right

Comment: @AndreyMolochko still this sounds wrong to me... these classes aren't absent... those private classes in Kotlin just don't become private classes in Java... but otherwise they aren't absent... and you do not see private classes in Java... but as Kotlin private classes aren't private classes in Java, they would be visible there... still... what was meant by "classes are absent in Java" and how was that verified? The OP found your answer useful, so do I... but it leaves that other question open...

Comment: @Roland
May be I said in wrong form. Private classes after compiling in byte code are not absent and don't disappear. These private classes turn into classes with default modificator.

Comment: .. probably just that sentence "private classes are absent in Java" should be revised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Kotlin code is compiled into Java byte code modificators `private`, `protected` and `public` is saved. But There are two exceptions, internal turns into `public`, because modificator internal is absent in java. And modificator `private` with class turns into `default`.